# SQLite Connection or SQLite Async Connection

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm start using sqlite for wp8 , from this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx)

I found that there're 2 version of SQliteConnection here: async and non-async. While I'm using this for WP8, I want to use the async version for smooth performance, but it seem the Async-version class doesn't implement IDispose ( I can use Using for the non-async version). So what solution should I use here ?

Comment: Not sure if the NuGet package Sqlite-net in the article is [this one](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/pull/305), if it is, as you can see, `SQLiteAsyncConnection` already implements IDisposable and can be used in a using statement.

Comment: You can use the normal version. There is almost no delay since your database file lies in the isostore. If you have large operations you can wrap it into a Task and perform your operations async.

Comment: @kennyzx from the article you sent, the author said that he hadn't updated the nuget package yet, so I think I've to wait :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would involve also consider the size of the project and the scope of it, for example if its a small project then just use the simple, non-async, it's less code and easier to maintain, and most of the small  operations happen in milliseconds.

If you want high performance, the go to async, write some extra code and get a better user experience.

Or maybe just use async for the large operations and non-async for the small ones?

I believe it's different for every project, and you could use a mixed approach sometimes, that's IMHO.